# Access .NET ushort[] array as uint16_t* without copying

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, native, mixed-mode

When converting ushort[] from c# to c++/cli to c++ do I have to copy all the data? or can I cast the pointer?

```
PreprocessorWrapper::Function1(ImageData^ rawImage)
{
    array<unsigned short>^ rawDataTemp = rawImage->RawData;
    bayer_raw_image* inputImage = new bayer_raw_image();
    inputImage->raw_data = (uint16_t*)rawDataTemp; //error is here
}
```

here is the error i'm getting

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'cli::array<Type> ^' to 'uint16_t
```

this is the C# class

```
public class ImageData
    {
       public int WidthColumns { get; set; }
        public int HeightLines { get; set; }
        public ushort[] RawData { get; set; }
        public ushort BitDepth { get; set; }
    }
```

c++ class

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t width;
    uint16_t height;
    uint16_t* raw_data;
    uint16_t bit_depth;
} bayer_raw_image;
```

Comment: You must pin the array so its address in memory is stable.  Use pin_ptr<> for short-lived cheap pins that last only as long as the method body, GCHandle::Alloc() for longer-lived pins.  If the pin lasts long (seconds) then you must copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to, but you'll have to **pin** it, as the GC is allowed to move managed objects in memory during a garbage collection.

```
array<uint16_t>^ rawDataTemp = rawImage->RawData;
pin_ptr<uint16_t> rawDataPinned = &rawDataTemp[0];
bayer_raw_image* inputImage = new bayer_raw_image();
inputImage->raw_data = rawDataPinned;
```

You should **not** make use of the pointer after `rawDataPinned` goes out of scope, as the data will no longer be pinned and will be subject to being moved around by the GC compaction. That's a nasty bug waiting to happen.

If you need long-term pinning, use a pinned `GCHandle`:

```
GCHandle::Alloc(rawImage->RawData, GCHandleType::Pinned)
```

It provides a `void*` to the first array item through `handle->AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer()`.
Don't forget to `Free()` it after use.

This is more heavyweight than `pin_ptr` as it needs to register a handle in the GC, whereas `pin_ptr` will only be noticed by the GC if a collection takes place while your object is pinned - it's as light as you can get.

Comment: Why the cast?  It should be an implicit conversion, and if you take out the cast, the compiler will let you know if you convert between unrelated types.

Comment: @Ben you're right, I just copy-pasted that line from the original code - fixed, thanks.